# Permissions in fi-ware COSMOS instance for hadoop commands

Tags: hadoop, fiware

Using the fiware COSMOS instance, i'm having some problems with permissions. I tried to solve this using chown and chmod but nothing changes and if I try to use sudo command the console ask me for a password that i don't know where to get it.

I have this problem when using hadoop commands like these ones:

```
hadoop fs -put
hadoop fs -mkdir
```

And when I use Hive CLI, for example to create a table, this problem apears again.

so, what can i do to get the permissions needed for hadoop commands?

Thanks.

***SOLVED***

I cant say why, but now, I completed the same basic example that the other day only asked for permissions[image: example completed without permissions problems]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, please? I.e. by printing the exact command and the output obtained. In addition, which is your username? **(Do not provide passwords)**

Comment: Thanks, but now I can make the example code without permissions problems.